# No puedo instalar composer

Tags: php7

Voy a comenzar un nuevo proyecto con laravel, installe laragon y luego instale composer pero este ultimo me muestra un error en el último paso :

> The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Éste es normalmente un error temporal durante la resolución de nombres de host y significa que el servidor local no recibió una respuesta de un servidor autoritativo.

> failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Éste es normalmente un error temporal durante la resolución de nombres de host y significa que el servidor local no recibió una respuesta de un servidor autoritativo.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar por favor?

Comment: en que S.O. lo vas a instalar? si es un linux basado en debian ya lo tienes en los repositorios, podrias instalarlo con apt-get

Comment: Es en Windows 10 es más fácil de instalar pero no se que sucede, yo le pongo el proxy de que conexion que tengoo en el navegador pero sigue el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Si usas Laragon no necesitas instalarlo nuevamente pues ya vienen incluído "de serie" en la carpeta

```
C:\laragon\bin\composer
```

Deberías incluir esta ruta en las variables de entorno de Windows para así poder usarlo desde cualquier ubicación sin tener que pasar la ruta.

Una vez hecho esto, ejecutaría el comando

```
composer self-update
```

Con esto actualizas composer a la última versión, que es lo más recomendable.

> PD. Aunque veo que es una pregunta antigua, dejo aquí la respuesta por
> si otro usuario necesita esta información.